# Migrating custom log4j levels from version 1.x to 2.0

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

Our application (Spring MVC) uses log4j 1.4 and has a custom log4J level (ALERT which extends Level). Now that we are migrating to log4j 2, how can I migrate the custom ALERT level to log4j 2?.

Per [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html), `LoggerConfigs will be assigned a Log Level. The set of possible levels includes (TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL). Note that in Log4j 2, the Level is an Enum and cannot be sub-classed. Users who desire more granularity are encouraged to use Markers instead.`

I am not sure how a Marker can replace a custom Log4J level. Any thoughts?

Comment: Keep looking in docs. The example shows how a marker can help you log things "which are not in the same level as everything else" http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html

Comment: Thanks @Alfabravo. I did look into the docs. Markers appear to be a way of filtering out certain logs, rather than customizing log levels. In example listed in link above, all of them are still logged at DEBUG level. What am I missing?